# Pjax and Yahoo Media Player

Tags: jquery, yui, yahoo-api, pjax

The site I'm working on is set up using Jquery and Pjax. I also have the Yahoo Media Player loaded through an external script. After clicking through pages with pjax doing the work, the player needs to be reinitialized. Does anyone know how to initialize the player after pjax load?

Comment: It seems the Yahoo! Web Player was discontinued: http://yahoo.tumblr.com/post/54125001066/keeping-our-focus-on-whats-next

Comment: @juandopazo The player is self hosted now, its not dependent on yahoo.